# R how to filter time series demography database based on size class

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, time-series

[1] **Background:** I have a dataset that includes individual measures of corals over time.  I am attempting to calculate growth within individual corals (ID) based on whether the coral was measured inside the desired size range (`Max Diameter (cm)` %in% c(1:10)) and then all proceeding measures UNTIL the first measure in which the coral either a.) leaves the size range or b.) shrinks or stays the same size.  This measure either leaving the range or shrinking/staying the same must be the LAST measure for that particular coral ID.

[2] **Filter Criteria:** This means that for each coral, the FIRST measure must be within the size range (1-10) (see filter(MinAbove != 1) in Code Attempted), and the LAST measure must either be **a.)** the first measurement outside the size range (1-10) or **b.)** the first measurement within the size range where the coral shrank or stayed the same size as the previous TimeStep (`Max Diameter (cm)`[TimeStep] >= `Max Diameter (cm)`[TimeStep + 1]).  This means that each coral should have AT LEAST two measurements and possibly more depending on how many successive measurements fell within the desired size range.  Lastly, if any gaps occur within the data where a coral was measured inside the range and then was not measured until multiple TimeSteps later (a coral was measured in the range at TimeStep == 1, was not measured in TimeStep == 2 because no row is present, and then next measured in TimeStep == 3) these corals should be completely removed from the database as all coral growth measurements are to be done stepwise by TimeStep in which growth is calculated always between successive TimeSteps.

[3] Here I have provided a dataset in which I have filtered for all measures taken of all corals that at some point had at least 1 measure that fell within the desired size range.  What I need is code to filter these measurements based on whether the coral meets the criteria from paragraph 2.

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(`Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR"), ID = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
22L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("H1033", "H1051", "H110", "H112", 
"H115", "H116", "H118", "H122", "H125", "H1289", "H171", "H172", 
"H174", "H177", "H186", "H187", "H188", "H191", "H192", "H236", 
"H237", "H244", "H254", "H274", "H293", "H30", "H332", "H37", 
"H374", "H410", "H466", "H479", "H482", "H499", "H531", "H560", 
"H580", "H593", "H597", "H644", "H647", "H649", "H653", "H66", 
"H693", "H695", "H699", "H70", "H700", "H712", "H716", "H728", 
"H76", "H760", "H765", "H804", "H854", "H863", "H911", "H926", 
"H96", "H963", "H969", "H98", "H985", "W1038", "W1064", "W1101", 
"W1152", "W1154", "W1192", "W1193", "W1208", "W1227", "W1243", 
"W1245", "W1315", "W1438", "W1494", "W1506", "W1537", "W1557", 
"W1636", "W1642", "W1655", "W1669", "W1675", "W1690", "W1708", 
"W1729", "W1741", "W1749", "W1758", "W1782", "W1785", "W1847", 
"W1919", "W2000", "W2004", "W2007", "W2011", "W2033", "W2044", 
"W2046", "W2131", "W234", "W246", "W249", "W251", "W307", "W355", 
"W359", "W369", "W374", "W433", "W450", "W461", "W470", "W542", 
"W544", "W584", "W601", "W606", "W79", "W807", "W872", "W887", 
"W923", "W952", "W956"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(18135, 
18226, 18135, 18226, 17386, 17484, 17575, 17680, 17783, 17862, 
17967, 18037, 18142, 18233, 17386, 17484, 17575, 17680, 17783, 
17862, 17967, 18037, 18142, 17386, 17575, 17680, 17783, 17862, 
17967, 18037, 18142, 18233, 17288, 17386, 17484, 17575, 17680, 
17783, 17862, 17967, 18037, 18142, 17288, 17386, 17386, 17484, 
17575, 17680, 17783, 17862, 17967, 18037, 18142, 18233, 17288, 
17386, 17484, 17575, 17680, 17783, 17862, 17967, 18037, 18142, 
18233, 17484, 17575, 17687), class = "Date"), Year = c("19", 
"19", "19", "19", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", 
"19", "19", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", 
"17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "17", "17", 
"17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "17", "17", 
"17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "19", "19", "17", "18", 
"18"), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", 
"Waikiki"), class = "factor"), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", "Low"), class = "factor"), `Module #` = c(216, 
216, 211, 211, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 216, 
216, 216), Side = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S"), Location = c("C3", "C3", 
"D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D1_2", 
"D1_2", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2_3", "D2", 
"D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"C3", "C3", "A3", "A2_3", "A3", "A2_3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
"A3", "A3", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A4", "A1", "A1", 
"A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1_2"), Settlement_Area = c(0.561677286, 
0.554087053, 0.46300425, 0.531316352, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.728662426, 0.75902336, 
0.743842893, 0.607218688, 0.637579622, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.728662426, 0.75902336, 
0.743842893, 0.607218688, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.728662426, 0.75902336, 0.743842893, 0.607218688, 
0.637579622, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.728662426, 0.75902336, 0.743842893, 
0.607218688, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.728662426, 0.75902336, 
0.743842893, 0.607218688, 0.637579622, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.728662426, 
0.75902336, 0.743842893, 0.607218688, 0.637579622, 0.75902336, 
0.75902336, 0.607218688), TimeStep = c(10, 11, 10, 11, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
3, 4, 5), size_class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 1, 1, 2), `Cover Code` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Max Diameter (cm)` = c(4, 6, 8, 12, 
4, 9, 13, 15, 17, 20, 20, 18, 20, 24, 9, 14, 19, 23, 48, 14, 
31, 32, 34, 7, 26, 32, 36, 42, 56, 55, 57, 44, 6, 8, 12, 12, 
20, 26, 31, 34, 27, 31, 4, 9, 2, 6, 10, 13, 13, 15, 22, 20, 16, 
5, 10, 19, 30, 36, 40, 45, 47, 46, 50, 63, 79, 10, 10, 13), `Max Orthogonal (cm)` = c(3.27467399642036, 
4.80721043211455, 6.33974686780875, 9.40481973919714, 3.27467399642036, 
7.10601508565585, 10.1710879570442, 11.7036243927384, 13.2361608284326, 
15, 18, 14.0024290462797, 18, 16, 7.10601508565585, 10.9373561748913, 
14.7686972641268, 19, 24, 10.9373561748913, 28, 30, 34, 5.57347864996165, 
18, 25, 28, 32, 40, 40, 46, 43, 4.80721043211455, 6.33974686780875, 
9.40481973919714, 9.40481973919714, 18, 19, 26, 25, 26, 27, 3.27467399642036, 
7.10601508565585, 1.74213756072616, 4.80721043211455, 7.87228330350294, 
10.1710879570442, 10.1710879570442, 11.7036243927384, 16, 15, 
12.4698926105855, 4.04094221426745, 7.87228330350294, 14.7686972641268, 
22, 28, 32, 38, 39, 37, 45, 60, 73, 7.87228330350294, 7.87228330350294, 
10.1710879570442), `Height (cm)` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 17, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1), `Status Code` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "W", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "PB", NA, NA, NA, "W", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), area_mm_squared = c(13.0986959856814, 28.8432625926873, 
50.71797494247, 112.857836870366, 13.0986959856814, 63.9541357709026, 
132.224143441575, 175.554365891076, 225.014734083355, 300, 360, 
252.043722833035, 360, 384, 63.9541357709026, 153.122986448479, 
280.60524801841, 437, 1152, 153.122986448479, 868, 960, 1156, 
39.0143505497316, 468, 800, 1008, 1344, 2240, 2200, 2622, 1892, 
28.8432625926873, 50.71797494247, 112.857836870366, 112.857836870366, 
360, 494, 806, 850, 702, 837, 13.0986959856814, 63.9541357709026, 
3.48427512145232, 28.8432625926873, 78.7228330350294, 132.224143441575, 
132.224143441575, 175.554365891076, 352, 300, 199.518281769368, 
20.2047110713373, 78.7228330350294, 280.60524801841, 660, 1008, 
1280, 1710, 1833, 1702, 2250, 3780, 5767, 78.7228330350294, 78.7228330350294, 
132.224143441575), area_cm_squared = c(0.130986959856814, 0.288432625926873, 
0.5071797494247, 1.12857836870366, 0.130986959856814, 0.639541357709026, 
1.32224143441575, 1.75554365891076, 2.25014734083355, 3, 3.6, 
2.52043722833035, 3.6, 3.84, 0.639541357709026, 1.53122986448479, 
2.8060524801841, 4.37, 11.52, 1.53122986448479, 8.68, 9.6, 11.56, 
0.390143505497316, 4.68, 8, 10.08, 13.44, 22.4, 22, 26.22, 18.92, 
0.288432625926873, 0.5071797494247, 1.12857836870366, 1.12857836870366, 
3.6, 4.94, 8.06, 8.5, 7.02, 8.37, 0.130986959856814, 0.639541357709026, 
0.0348427512145232, 0.288432625926873, 0.787228330350294, 1.32224143441575, 
1.32224143441575, 1.75554365891076, 3.52, 3, 1.99518281769368, 
0.202047110713373, 0.787228330350294, 2.8060524801841, 6.6, 10.08, 
12.8, 17.1, 18.33, 17.02, 22.5, 37.8, 57.67, 0.787228330350294, 
0.787228330350294, 1.32224143441575), Volume_mm_cubed = c(6.85846118003715, 
15.1022969777913, 26.5558695807025, 59.092225201996, 6.85846118003715, 
33.486307184092, 69.2323996105425, 91.9200510315034, 117.817439257621, 
157.07963267949, 188.495559215388, 131.969784672614, 188.495559215388, 
201.061929829747, 33.486307184092, 80.1750082203783, 146.924564288896, 
228.812664936457, 603.18578948924, 80.1750082203783, 1363.45121165797, 
1507.9644737231, 3631.6811075498, 20.4278661786023, 245.044226980004, 
7120.94334813686, 527.787565803085, 1407.43350880823, 2345.72251468038, 
2303.83461263252, 2745.75197923748, 1981.29776686396, 15.1022969777913, 
26.5558695807025, 59.092225201996, 59.092225201996, 188.495559215388, 
258.65779514556, 422.020613132229, 890.117918517108, 735.132680940011, 
876.504350351552, 6.85846118003715, 33.486307184092, 1.82436218744005, 
15.1022969777913, 41.2191789887707, 69.2323996105425, 69.2323996105425, 
91.9200510315034, 184.306769010601, 314.159265358979, 104.467528043918, 
10.5791619782696, 41.2191789887707, 146.924564288896, 345.575191894877, 
527.787565803085, 1340.41286553164, 1790.70781254618, 1919.51311134336, 
1782.33023213661, 2356.19449019234, 7916.81348704628, 12078.3765555016, 
41.2191789887707, 41.2191789887707, 69.2323996105425), Volume_cm_cubed = c(0.00685846118003715, 
0.0151022969777913, 0.0265558695807025, 0.059092225201996, 0.00685846118003715, 
0.033486307184092, 0.0692323996105425, 0.0919200510315034, 0.117817439257621, 
0.15707963267949, 0.188495559215388, 0.131969784672614, 0.188495559215388, 
0.201061929829747, 0.033486307184092, 0.0801750082203783, 0.146924564288896, 
0.228812664936457, 0.60318578948924, 0.0801750082203783, 1.36345121165797, 
1.5079644737231, 3.6316811075498, 0.0204278661786023, 0.245044226980004, 
7.12094334813686, 0.527787565803085, 1.40743350880823, 2.34572251468038, 
2.30383461263252, 2.74575197923748, 1.98129776686396, 0.0151022969777913, 
0.0265558695807025, 0.059092225201996, 0.059092225201996, 0.188495559215388, 
0.25865779514556, 0.422020613132229, 0.890117918517108, 0.735132680940011, 
0.876504350351552, 0.00685846118003715, 0.033486307184092, 0.00182436218744005, 
0.0151022969777913, 0.0412191789887707, 0.0692323996105425, 0.0692323996105425, 
0.0919200510315034, 0.184306769010601, 0.314159265358979, 0.104467528043918, 
0.0105791619782696, 0.0412191789887707, 0.146924564288896, 0.345575191894877, 
0.527787565803085, 1.34041286553164, 1.79070781254618, 1.91951311134336, 
1.78233023213661, 2.35619449019234, 7.91681348704628, 12.0783765555016, 
0.0412191789887707, 0.0412191789887707, 0.0692323996105425), 
    MD = c(4, 6, 8, 12, 4, 9, 13, 15, 17, 20, 20, 18, 20, 24, 
    9, 14, 19, 23, 48, 14, 31, 32, 34, 7, 26, 32, 36, 42, 56, 
    55, 57, 44, 6, 8, 12, 12, 20, 26, 31, 34, 27, 31, 4, 9, 2, 
    6, 10, 13, 13, 15, 22, 20, 16, 5, 10, 19, 30, 36, 40, 45, 
    47, 46, 50, 63, 79, 10, 10, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -68L), groups = structure(list(
    ID = c("H1033", "H1051", "H110", "H112", "H115", "H116", 
    "H118", "H122", "H125", "H244"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:14, 
        15:23, 24:32, 33:42, 43:44, 45:54, 55:65, 66:68)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Desired Database

```
data_desired <- structure(list(`Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("H1033", "H1051", "H110", "H112", 
"H115", "H116", "H118", "H122", "H125", "H1289", "H171", "H172", 
"H174", "H177", "H186", "H187", "H188", "H191", "H192", "H236", 
"H237", "H244", "H254", "H274", "H293", "H30", "H332", "H37", 
"H374", "H410", "H466", "H479", "H482", "H499", "H531", "H560", 
"H580", "H593", "H597", "H644", "H647", "H649", "H653", "H66", 
"H693", "H695", "H699", "H70", "H700", "H712", "H716", "H728", 
"H76", "H760", "H765", "H804", "H854", "H863", "H911", "H926", 
"H96", "H963", "H969", "H98", "H985", "W1038", "W1064", "W1101", 
"W1152", "W1154", "W1192", "W1193", "W1208", "W1227", "W1243", 
"W1245", "W1315", "W1438", "W1494", "W1506", "W1537", "W1557", 
"W1636", "W1642", "W1655", "W1669", "W1675", "W1690", "W1708", 
"W1729", "W1741", "W1749", "W1758", "W1782", "W1785", "W1847", 
"W1919", "W2000", "W2004", "W2007", "W2011", "W2033", "W2044", 
"W2046", "W2131", "W234", "W246", "W249", "W251", "W307", "W355", 
"W359", "W369", "W374", "W433", "W450", "W461", "W470", "W542", 
"W544", "W584", "W601", "W606", "W79", "W807", "W872", "W887", 
"W923", "W952", "W956"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(18135, 
18226, 18135, 18226, 17386, 17484, 17575, 17386, 17484, 17288, 
17386, 17484, 17288, 17386, 17386, 17484, 17575, 17680, 17288, 
17386, 17484, 17575), class = "Date"), Year = c("19", "19", "19", 
"19", "17", "17", "18", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", 
"17", "17", "18", "18", "17", "17", "17", "18"), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Hanauma Bay", "Waikiki"), class = "factor"), 
    Shelter = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low"), class = "factor"), `Module #` = c(216, 216, 211, 
    211, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
    215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 216, 216), Side = c("N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
    "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S"), Location = c("C3", "C3", 
    "D3", "D3", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1_2", "D1_2", "D3", "D3", 
    "D3", "C3", "C3", "A3", "A2_3", "A3", "A2_3", "A1", "A1", 
    "B1", "B1"), Settlement_Area = c(0.561677286, 0.554087053, 
    0.46300425, 0.531316352, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 
    0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336, 0.75902336
    ), TimeStep = c(10, 11, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
    2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4), size_class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), `Cover Code` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
    NA, NA, 1, 1), `Max Diameter (cm)` = c(4, 6, 8, 12, 4, 9, 
    13, 9, 14, 6, 8, 12, 4, 9, 2, 6, 10, 13, 10, 19, 10, 10), 
    `Max Orthogonal (cm)` = c(3.27467399642036, 4.80721043211455, 
    6.33974686780875, 9.40481973919714, 3.27467399642036, 7.10601508565585, 
    10.1710879570442, 7.10601508565585, 10.9373561748913, 4.80721043211455, 
    6.33974686780875, 9.40481973919714, 3.27467399642036, 7.10601508565585, 
    1.74213756072616, 4.80721043211455, 7.87228330350294, 10.1710879570442, 
    7.87228330350294, 14.7686972641268, 7.87228330350294, 7.87228330350294
    ), `Height (cm)` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Status Code` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), area_mm_squared = c(13.0986959856814, 28.8432625926873, 
    50.71797494247, 112.857836870366, 13.0986959856814, 63.9541357709026, 
    132.224143441575, 63.9541357709026, 153.122986448479, 28.8432625926873, 
    50.71797494247, 112.857836870366, 13.0986959856814, 63.9541357709026, 
    3.48427512145232, 28.8432625926873, 78.7228330350294, 132.224143441575, 
    78.7228330350294, 280.60524801841, 78.7228330350294, 78.7228330350294
    ), area_cm_squared = c(0.130986959856814, 0.288432625926873, 
    0.5071797494247, 1.12857836870366, 0.130986959856814, 0.639541357709026, 
    1.32224143441575, 0.639541357709026, 1.53122986448479, 0.288432625926873, 
    0.5071797494247, 1.12857836870366, 0.130986959856814, 0.639541357709026, 
    0.0348427512145232, 0.288432625926873, 0.787228330350294, 
    1.32224143441575, 0.787228330350294, 2.8060524801841, 0.787228330350294, 
    0.787228330350294), Volume_mm_cubed = c(6.85846118003715, 
    15.1022969777913, 26.5558695807025, 59.092225201996, 6.85846118003715, 
    33.486307184092, 69.2323996105425, 33.486307184092, 80.1750082203783, 
    15.1022969777913, 26.5558695807025, 59.092225201996, 6.85846118003715, 
    33.486307184092, 1.82436218744005, 15.1022969777913, 41.2191789887707, 
    69.2323996105425, 41.2191789887707, 146.924564288896, 41.2191789887707, 
    41.2191789887707), Volume_cm_cubed = c(0.00685846118003715, 
    0.0151022969777913, 0.0265558695807025, 0.059092225201996, 
    0.00685846118003715, 0.033486307184092, 0.0692323996105425, 
    0.033486307184092, 0.0801750082203783, 0.0151022969777913, 
    0.0265558695807025, 0.059092225201996, 0.00685846118003715, 
    0.033486307184092, 0.00182436218744005, 0.0151022969777913, 
    0.0412191789887707, 0.0692323996105425, 0.0412191789887707, 
    0.146924564288896, 0.0412191789887707, 0.0412191789887707
    ), MD = c(4, 6, 8, 12, 4, 9, 13, 9, 14, 6, 8, 12, 4, 9, 2, 
    6, 10, 13, 10, 19, 10, 10), Skipped = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), Shrank_stasis = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), InRange = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), AboveRange = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), RLE = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), MinIn = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), MinAbove = c(Inf, Inf, 11, 11, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, Inf, Inf, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5), MinInTime = c(10, 10, 
    10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
    3), MinShrink_stasis = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 8, 8, 8, 7, 
    7, 4, 4, 4, Inf, Inf, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 4, 4), MinSkipped = c(Inf, 
    Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, 
    Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), groups = structure(list(
    ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 22L), .Label = c("H1033", 
    "H1051", "H110", "H112", "H115", "H116", "H118", "H122", 
    "H125", "H1289", "H171", "H172", "H174", "H177", "H186", 
    "H187", "H188", "H191", "H192", "H236", "H237", "H244", "H254", 
    "H274", "H293", "H30", "H332", "H37", "H374", "H410", "H466", 
    "H479", "H482", "H499", "H531", "H560", "H580", "H593", "H597", 
    "H644", "H647", "H649", "H653", "H66", "H693", "H695", "H699", 
    "H70", "H700", "H712", "H716", "H728", "H76", "H760", "H765", 
    "H804", "H854", "H863", "H911", "H926", "H96", "H963", "H969", 
    "H98", "H985", "W1038", "W1064", "W1101", "W1152", "W1154", 
    "W1192", "W1193", "W1208", "W1227", "W1243", "W1245", "W1315", 
    "W1438", "W1494", "W1506", "W1537", "W1557", "W1636", "W1642", 
    "W1655", "W1669", "W1675", "W1690", "W1708", "W1729", "W1741", 
    "W1749", "W1758", "W1782", "W1785", "W1847", "W1919", "W2000", 
    "W2004", "W2007", "W2011", "W2033", "W2044", "W2046", "W2131", 
    "W234", "W246", "W249", "W251", "W307", "W355", "W359", "W369", 
    "W374", "W433", "W450", "W461", "W470", "W542", "W544", "W584", 
    "W601", "W606", "W79", "W807", "W872", "W887", "W923", "W952", 
    "W956"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8:9, 
        10:12, 13:14, 15:18, 19:20, 21:22)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I have attempted to use RLE from the data.table package to iterate changes within the `Max Diameter (cm)` to see transitions from being inside and outside the desired size range.

#### Code Attempted

```
size_vect <- seq(from = 1, to = 10,by = 1)

data_new <- data %>% group_by(ID, TimeStep) %>%
  arrange(ID, TimeStep) %>% 
  mutate(Shrank = case_when(lag(`Max Diameter (cm)`[TimeStep], n = 1) > `Max Diameter (cm)`[TimeStep] ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(InRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` >= min(size_vect) & `Max Diameter (cm)` <= max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                             TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(AboveRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` > max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                                TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(RLE = data.table::rleid(InRange)) %>% 
  mutate(MinIn = min(RLE[InRange]), MinAbove = min(RLE[AboveRange]), MinInTime = min(TimeStep[InRange]), MinShrink = min(TimeStep[Shrank])) %>% 
    filter(MinAbove != 1,
           MinIn < MinAbove & (TimeStep == MinInTime | (TimeStep == MinInTime + 1))) %>% 
          filter(TimeStep <= MinShrink)
```

However, I have not been able to obtain the desired output through this code thus far and am open to either editing this code or taking an entirely new approach (whatever is easiest).  Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my database to include some more data and was able to alter the code I originally provided to obtain the desired_data

```
size_vect <- seq(from = 1, to = 10,by = 1)

data_new <- data  %>% 
  arrange(ID,TimeStep) %>%
  mutate(Skipped = case_when(TimeStep - lag(TimeStep) > 1 ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(Shrank_stasis = case_when(lag(`Max Diameter (cm)`, n = 1) >= `Max Diameter (cm)`~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(InRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` >= min(size_vect) & `Max Diameter (cm)` <= max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                             TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(AboveRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` > max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                                TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(RLE = data.table::rleid(InRange)) %>% 
  mutate(MinIn = min(RLE[InRange]), MinAbove = min(TimeStep[AboveRange]), MinInTime = min(TimeStep[InRange]), MinShrink_stasis = min(TimeStep[Shrank_stasis]), MinSkipped = min(TimeStep[Skipped])) %>% 
  filter(MinAbove != 1, # gets rid of all corals that started above the desired size range
         MinIn < MinAbove, # ensures corals started in the range
         TimeStep <= MinAbove & TimeStep <= MinShrink_stasis) %>% # filters for measures before and including when it goes above the size range (a) and filters for measures before and including the first measure when shrinkage or stasis occurs (b)
  filter(is.infinite(MinSkipped))
```

This solution incorporates all criteria and maintains at least two measures per coral with some corals having more measures as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I think you used the wrong group when grouping by TimeStep, it doens't make much sense.

```
data_new <- data %>%
  arrange(ID,TimeStep) %>%
  mutate(Shrank = case_when(lag(`Max Diameter (cm)`, n = 1) > `Max Diameter (cm)`~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(InRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` >= min(size_vect) & `Max Diameter (cm)` <= max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                             TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  mutate(AboveRange = case_when(`Max Diameter (cm)` > max(size_vect) ~ TRUE,
                                TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(RLE = data.table::rleid(InRange)) %>% 
  mutate(MinIn = min(RLE[InRange]), MinAbove = min(RLE[AboveRange]), MinInTime = min(TimeStep[InRange]), MinShrink = min(TimeStep[Shrank])) %>% 
  filter(MinAbove != 1,
         MinIn < MinAbove & (TimeStep == MinInTime | (TimeStep == MinInTime + 1))) %>% 
  filter(TimeStep <= MinShrink)
```

Comment: Ya it's a work in progress as far as code goes.  I'm lost in regards to how to get what I have in the desired data frame.  Right now it is set up to have only 2 measures per coral (the first measure in the range and the following measurement.  However this is not what I want as I detailed in the description and have in the desired dataframe.  I am unsure about how to code it.

Comment: I think I fixed the lag() part your groups only had one member each, the rest is too long to solve as one question

Comment: Could you say what exactly changed with your edit?  I have the same number of rows in my provided code as I do in your edit.  Just want to know so I can split this up into component questions if appropriate as you suggest.  What I am generally looking for is code that increases my sample size (aka more than 2 measures per coral).  I am planning on using a lmer random effect for coral `ID` to account for repeated measures of growth for a single coral colony

Comment: I removed TimeStep from the group

Comment: It's interesting that your change didn't change the number of rows (227).  Like I said in the post, if you have an idea for a different solution from my code (which I am sure there are far better, elegant solutions out there) then feel free.  I am not married at all to the code I have.  I just presented it because of the RLE method that may or may not be useful for finding a solution that matches data_desired

Comment: My solution only returns 17 rows

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your help!  I incorporated your part of the solution into my own that I have posted below.  I was able to make a couple of new variables to filter by